# One Method Accepting Two Different Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two methods, one to check-in internal users and another to check-in external users. The method is the same except for the object (see code). I was wondering if it's possible to have one method that would accept both objects. I want to pass a parameter that says if it's internal or external, and based on that I want to call the respective object and save it. Not sure if it's possible.

```
public JsonResult CheckInInternal(int ID)
{
    var e = EventInternal.Get(ID, EventInternal.FetchType.ID);

    if (e.ID == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Registration ID not found.");
    }
    if (DateTime.Now.Date > e.EventDetail.StartTime.Date)
    {
        throw new Exception("Check-in has been closed for this class!");
    }
    e.CheckedIn = true;
    e.Save();
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success!" });
}

public JsonResult CheckInExternal(int ID)
{
    var e = EventExternal.Get(ID, EventExternal.FetchType.ID);

    if (e.ID == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Registration ID not found.");
    }
    if (DateTime.Now.Date > e.EventDetail.StartTime.Date)
    {
        throw new Exception("Check-in has been closed for this class!");
    }
    e.CheckedIn = true;
    e.Save();
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success!" });
}
```

Comment: What are `EventInternal` and `EventExternal`?

Comment: Take a look at Generics.

Comment: yes you can have a single method that can handle both types.. your parameters would be `Integer and Enum`

Comment: Generics and enums aside. I think having an interface to hold EventExternal/Internal is good. Let the method receive the interface and you are done

Comment: Could I see some sample code? What would be the best approach?

Comment: This is typically solved by having a superclass, for both: EvenInternal and EventExternal which declares the method Save, the ID and all common things both classes share. The your method should take as parameter this base class. The run-time will call the corresponding methods in the lower class. Piece of cake. You can also declare an interface instead of a base class. But that's mostly up to you.

Comment: Above code is incorrect. Close the method brackets properly.

Comment: What is the return type for the EventInternal and EventExternal `Get` methods? Are those types related somehow so you could process them generically?

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is the best way, but you can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public enum CallType
{
 Internal, External
}
public JsonResult CheckInInternalOrExternal(int ID, CallType type)
    {
         object e = type == CallType.Internal? EventInternal.Get(ID, EventInternal.FetchType.ID) as object : EventExternal.Get(ID, EventExternal.FetchType.ID) as object;

         var idProperty = e.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
         var idValue = Convert.ToInt32(IdProperty.GetValue(e));

         if (idValue == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Registration ID not found.");
            }
         if (DateTime.Now.Date > e.EventDetail.StartTime.Date)
            {
                throw new Exception("Check-in has been closed for this class!");
            }

         var checkedInProperty = e.GetType().GetProperty("CheckedIn");
         checkedInProperty.SetValue(e, true);

         var saveMethod = e.GetType().GetMethod("Save");
         saveMethod.Invoke(e);

         return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success!" });
    }
```

But as some commenters are saying, `Interface` or `Generics` is the best solution. Depending on your scenario.